# Using Jest's todo feature

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

The [release notes for Jest 24](https://jestjs.io/blog/2019/01/25/jest-24-refreshing-polished-typescript-friendly#testtodo) highlighted a new feature that I want to make use of: `test.todo`. However, for the life of my I am unable to use it.

For example, I want to sketch out tests in my `subscriptions.test.ts` file so I create the following:

```javascript
describe('Subscription Tests', () => {
    test.todo('... a name');
});
```

The TypeScript compiler then promptly presents me with a red line under `todo` saying, `Property 'todo' does not exist on type 'It'.`

I am sure I am missing something obvious but I've hit the wall at this point. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you updated `@types/jest`, too? `todo` is [DefinitelyThere](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8a8fe2ba56b3cbb22c31d8450f417a9bd93d7596/types/jest/index.d.ts#L293).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @jonrsharpe I ran `yarn upgrade @types/jest --latest` and that resolved my problem. Urgh -- could not see the wood for the trees!

Comment: `npm i @types/jest@latest --save-dev` for the npm users :)

Answer (score 3):

I feel pretty dumb for a while because my test was failing after adding the [`todo()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testtodoname). I shoud've read the documentation more thoroughly. Here is my problematic code:

```js
test("should show progress indicator when authorizing", () => {
  test.todo("should show progress indicator when authorizing")
})
```

But it need to be like the below. Passing callback when using `todo` and nested `test()` in the callback are not allowed.

```js
test.todo("should show progress indicator when authorizing")
```